# JWT Authorization via header throws CORS Error

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, http, jwt

I want to create an object and send the JWT token via headers. It works perfectly fine if I skip the Authorization. However, once I enable the access restriction, I either get a CORS Error or an "Access Denied" message.

**The api call**

```
  editMediaObject(data): Observable<any> {
    var url = `${ApiServerUrl}/edit_mo`;
    url = encodeURI(url);
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
      "Authorization": "..."  // Just the token, hardcoded for testing
      }
    return from(this.httpAdvanced.post(url, data, headers)).pipe(map(res => res.data));
  }
```

**edit_mo.php**

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    include_once '../users/validate_token.php';

    if ($validate_check) {
```

**validate_token.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/core.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/BeforeValidException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/ExpiredException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
include_once '../libs/php-jwt-master/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $jwt = $headers['Authorization'];
} else {
    $jwt = "";
}

if($jwt){

    try {
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
        http_response_code(200);    
        $validate_check = TRUE;     
    }

 catch (Exception $e){

    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode(array(
        "message" => "Access denied.",
        "error" => $e->getMessage()
    ));
    $validate_check = FALSE;
}
}

else{

    $validate_check = FALSE;

    // set response code
    http_response_code(401);

    // tell the user access denied
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Access denied."));
}
?>
```

---

Am I adding the headers correctly? Do I need to change something in my header settings?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: CORS has blocked following request [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and I found a solution that will get you past the error. However, I am not sure that it is the best solution. It basically makes it so that you can send from any origin. I didn't write this code, and unfortunately I can't remember where I got it, to give credit where credit is due.

If anyone has a better solution, I am also interested to hear it.

This will get you past your dreaded error at least:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Authorization: *");

// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```